# Android SDK manager not opening from Visual Studio

Tags: android, sdk, vs-community-edition

I am having problems getting android SDK Manager to open from Visual Studio, it opens fine launching from Android Studio, but in Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 its not working, something flashes up but then instantly closes.

Has anyone got a solution to this?  I have seen a lot of information about how to correct and SDK Manager that does not open at all, but that's not my issue, so posting this issue as its more focused on the issue from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours I managed to get this working, I changed the Java version from a 32 bit to a 64 bit version, this solved it the problem.